# Create a quad that faces a given normal

Tags: mathematics, geometry, normals

Let's imagine that we have a given normal, (it could be done with source and destination points but let's say that source is 0 0 0 and the destination has been already normalized)

What could be the easiest way to create a Quad with side S that points to that normal?

Obviously, we could create an M4x4 and transform vertex per vertex, but it could be too costly, I assume that there could be an easier/faster method.

Thank you in advance for any tip!

Comment: There are infinitely many possible quads that have a given normal. Do you have more parameters (e.g. position and scale)? Edit: Oh, and I wrote that before thinking a quad might not even be a rectangle.

Comment: If you can't find an answer on the other question, please edit your question and make sure to highlight why it's different.